# jQuery Autocomplete Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, autocomplete

I've implemented the jQuery UI Autocomplete function and am having noticible performance issues.

Originally, I had it sending a new query on each character which is entered (but minimum 3 must be entered).

My database is indexed, has 50k rows of data (5 columns). I have no performance issues at the DB level.

One technique I decided to try was to cache the JSON and point autocomplete to that versus the database. This worked perfect... up to 2000 rows or so. Beyond that, it become slow and wonky.

If anyone has a recommendation on techniques I would appreciate it.

Here's some code to give you an idea of the Javascript.

```
// First, setup some data to iterate over. 
// My thought is to query the DB once, and build this list in memory to avoid autocomplete hitting the database each keystroke.        

var data = []; 
    data.push({value: "Person 1", label: "Person 1"});
    data.push({value: "Person 2", label: "Person 2"});

$("#searchBox").autocomplete({
    source: data;
    minChars: 3;
    delay: 0;
});
```

Comment: Upfront suggestion: have some delay time

Comment: What exactly does that solve?

Comment: @JasonWells users hopefully typed more chars before actually request data, meaning smaller result set, quicker performance.

Comment: You don't re-query the server instantaneously at each query stroke. If the user is searching for "Adrian", it will not query immediately when user types 'A', it waits the `delay` time for the next key stroke. That way, query will only usually run if the user has finished typing his key word [but that might not help if user is really slow at typing :) ]

Answer (score 2):

50k rows !!!!  The network is almost certainly your bottleneck. Use TOP or LIMIT (Don't know what db you are using) Surely user is never going to scan 50,000 results just bring back first 10 while they continue typing.

edit

Ah I misread your question, the table has 50k rows, not that you're returning 50k rows Doh! 
But then you do mention caching 2k rows so... Just limit the results with TOP and work your way up until it gets too slow, find trade off that suits

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008. I as suggesting caching the result set in memory in order to make autocomplete nearly instant. Works beautifully for a result set under 2000 :)

Comment: I still think your suggestion is valid. The top 10~20 should do it. If not, user would keep searching

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, what exactly are we caching in your solution? In my above comment, I was suggesting we query the DB once, cache the result set in JSON, and then point autocomplete to that JSON (much faster), but it starts to bark at 2000. The point would be to avoid hitting the DB all together.

Comment: The 2000 issue is probably DOM operations, appending thousands of elements. The last time I did this I just returned top 10 most relevant results and then appended a "more..." row to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use any DB on server side, all indexes stored in the
flat files, and to client sending "answer window" only.

You can use my solution, take source here: http://enumer.org/ac-dist.tgz

This works very quick, an handles huge dictionaries: 10M+ records OK.

Works under Apache WEB-server, with FastCGI module on Unix like OS.
My demo works on the old machine: Celeron-300 DeskPro, and this hardware
is enough for work as quick as you see.

Server part written on C++, client: JavaScript+Ajax.

Source codes are free upon request.

Comment: Hello,
Could you publish your demo/source code again ? The link is dead since. Or explain a bit more your code so I can work based on your solution. Thx

Comment: Really, my web-site was dead, and I do not want restore it quick. However, I copied tgz-source to http://enumer.org/ac-dist.tgz and edited answer above. Please, take and use.